# How to get email which was first given to a android phone?

Tags: android, kotlin, accountmanager

I am making a android app where I need primary email which was given at time when phone was booted first time.
After digging up people said that is not possible instead go for first email that will be oldest
I have a Kotlin code which I am using to retrieve the email
Code is as follows:

```
fun getEmail(context: Context?): String? {
    val accountManager = AccountManager.get(context)
    val account = getAccount(accountManager)
    return account?.name
}
private fun getAccount(accountManager: AccountManager): Account? {
    val accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google")
    val account: Account?
    account = if (accounts.isNotEmpty()) {
        accounts[0]
    } else {
        null
    }
    return account
}
```

When I call getEmail() function it returns me null instead of email

I have also added the following permissions in Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

How do I retrieve the emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me
Manifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
```

Kotlin

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState
    Log.d(TAG,"${getAccount(AccountManager.get(this))}")

}
    private fun getAccount(accountManager: AccountManager): Account? {
        val accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google")
        val account: Account? = if (accounts.isNotEmpty()) {
            accounts[0]
        } else {
            null
        }
        return account
    }
```

console result :

Account {name=bensalahaymen@gmail.com, type=com.google}

Comment: I tried this it returns me null still :v

Comment: Thank you it works , I just had to change the max SDK version to my current Sdk and now it works

Comment: Very nice that's good